# How to access page from other functions in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Hi I try to get src of image in other function but page is not defined, when i try to delete function (make only async, and put browser and page in this) it doesn't work

```
(async function main() {
  try{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:true, 
      args:[
        '--start-maximized',
        '--window-size=1920,1080'
      ]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(site);
    //await page.waitForSelector('#sd-current > div > div.sd-message > div > img')
    //const imgs = await page.$$eval('#sd-current > div > div.sd-message > div > img', imgs => imgs.map(img => img.getAttribute('src')));
    console.debug(getImageSrc());
    await browser.close();
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();

async function getImageSrc() {
  await page.waitForSelector('#sd-current > div > div.sd-message > div > img');
  const imgs = await page.$$eval('#sd-current > div > div.sd-message > div > img', imgs => imgs.map(img => img.getAttribute('src')));
  return imgs.toString();
}
```

Comment: Declare the variable outside `main()` and assign it inside `main()`. Be sure to make it not constant.

Comment: return gives me something like this 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\index.js
Promise {[[PromiseState]]: 'pending', [[PromiseResult]]: undefined, Symbol(async_id_symbol): 4829, Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol): 544}
'

Comment: Pass a parameter to the function: `async function getImageSrc(page) {}` and call it with `getImageSrc(page)`. Also be sure to `await` the async func: `console.debug(await getImageSrc());`

Comment: I should give await first, thanks <3